# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'

Tags: c#

[image: Screenshot]

```
private void SetAccessLevel(string UserName)
{
    SqlCommand cmd_SetAccessLevel = new SqlCommand();
    cmd_SetAccessLevel.CommandText = "inset into tblAccessLevel(User_Name,Can_Add_User,Can_Change_Backcolor) values (@User_Name,@Can_Add_User,@Can_Change_Backcolor)";
    cmd_SetAccessLevel.Connection = con;
    cmd_SetAccessLevel.Parameters.Add("@User_Name",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=UserName;
    cmd_SetAccessLevel.Parameters.Add("@Can_Add_User",SqlDbType.Bit).Value=true;
    cmd_SetAccessLevel.Parameters.Add("@Can_Change_Backcolor", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = true;
    cmd_SetAccessLevel.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Additional information:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'

Comment: You have a typo in your sql statement. it should be insert instead of inset.

Comment: Insert not Inset  (with "r")

Comment: Are you sure that your command string meets `INSERT INTO ...` -> `INSERT` not INSET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**insert not inset**

Simple typo... Fix and them try again.

Also try to post the code here instead of imaging it out. It's easier for us.

Answer (score 2):

Typo: "**INSET** INTO"

Should be: `INSERT INTO`